# A thread does not access synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a sudden issue in Production code which was not happening since the last 5-6 years. I have a Thread Pool that spawns a maximum of 64 threads, and all 64 threads read some data and put it in a common `Map` for further processing.

The read is done by all threads from a specific source, and I have verified that the data is indeed getting read from the source, however, one particular batch is not getting put in the `Map`.

Here is a code snippet (cannot put whole code due to confidentiality issues):

```
try {
   <read the data>
    .
    .
    <do processing>
    .
    .
    synchronized(glock) { //glock is a class attribute, Object glock = new Object[];
     map.put(<data that was read>);
     log.debug("bla bla bla")
    }
} catch(Throwable e) { 
     log.error("error") 
  }
  finally {
    log.debug("done")
 }
```

**ISSUE: A particular thread does not go into the synchronized block, does not put into the map, does not print `"bla bla bla"`, does not print `"error"` but it prints `"done"`.**

I have verified everything...nothing has changed in the code, this issue has appeared immediately from nowhere. The problem is, I cannot put any additional logs since it is production code without getting all clients agree, but that is the last part.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or know anything about it? The data being read is huge, 6000 records and each record having a minimum 0f 30-40 columns of data.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Catching `Throwable` and not `Exception`**

Comment: Is there a `try`/`finally` in the code somewhere?

Comment: Post the actual code. What you posted carries almost no information.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Edited for the try....catch. Prints what is in the "finally", does not cause an exception.

Comment: @npe: cant, client restrictions....but I have pretty much verified the part which I have omitted works, the issue is only around synchronized block.

Comment: I'll start with the obvious: 1. Look for `return` statements inside the `try` block. 2. Look for exceptions (and [errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)) that are not caught in the `catch` block.

Comment: There are not enough details to solve your problem.  Also, generally speaking, posting a well known algorithm will not hurt your NDA.  Just dont post us the csv file you are parsing.  I AM NOT A LAWYER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 99% chance that something is wrong with your code. This means the code in the `synchronized` block throws an exception but you don't see it.

The usual culprits are:

- Empty `catch` block which swallows exceptions (can be elsewhere in the code)
- Unusual log config for the logger in the `catch` block which, for example, writes exceptions into a different log file
- Log messages aren't written in order for some reason (so the ERROR line is not where you expect it)
- Some unusual condition (like out of memory) plus resilient code prevents writing of the log messages. Maps can need surprising amounts of memory.
- `log` isn't a standard Java logger but something else.

There is a small (< 1%) chance that you found a bug in your VM or there is a hardware issue. If you can get the same results repeatedly, it's *probably* not a hardware issue.

If everything else fails, you will need to debug the issue in production. Of course, your client will object; at that time, you will let them decide which is more important to them: Some rule that you mustn't debug the code or fixing the bug.

Comment: Finally we did not convince the client...he chose to put an additional check (in the Unix script that calls the code) and fail the event if this condition occurs....and restart the job again.

Comment: If you can, check whether earlier runs of the script created correct results. Errors like this sometimes cause corrupt data in the database.

Answer (score 3):

From what you showed us it seems, that

```
synchronized(glock){}
```

throws an exception while putting the data unto the map, not printing the "bla bla bla".
"done" is printed because it in the `finally` block of the `try`.

Comment: The code might throw an `Error`; `Error`s don't inherit from `Exception` so the code above doesn't catch them. This probably means that somewhere up the call stack, the error is swallowed. A famous kind of `Error` is `AssertError`

Comment: If the `synchronized(glock){}` did cause an exception, wouldnt it go into the `catch(Throwable e)`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla but an Error is usually an unrecoverable nastyness that would let itself be known one way or another.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Updated, I verified, code is using `Throwable`. Sorry, missed it.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: I only wish I could, I cannot debug, the code is deployed on Unix, I have code base in SVN windows, cannot debug and test, have to rely only on logs. I tried re-producing the issue in QA, but it runs perfect in QA. The issue is with Production only.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: That depends how resilient the application and the VM are. There are applications that won't exit, no matter the error. And it just takes one empty/broken `catch` block to ruin your day.

Comment: @DhwaneetBhatt: Java can be configured for remote debugging. What else prevents you from debugging it?